# Hide Url tooltip of an anchor in IE Kiosk mode

Tags: .net, html, internet-explorer

I am running a web page in Internet explorer in Kiosk Mode. When the mouse comes over a Link the Url is displayed at the bottom left corner of the screen.

Is there any way to hide this?

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to redirect the page and call the javascript function on click event.

```
<script>
  function redir()
  {
    window.location = "http://google.com";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I have to implement a solution for submit buttons as well. If I have to apply this solution to the submit buttons as well then this will be too much work for nothing. Is there any sort of tweak in IE Settings that we can do?

Comment: I dont think so, but only thing you can do to hide the URL's is you can make the user redirect from code behind